# Radio button group checked property css error

Tags: html, css

I made the tabs using radio button trick like this

Html

```
<div class="tabs">
   <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
   <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
   <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
   <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label> 
</div>
```

then css:

```
.tabs label {
   margin-left: -1px;
   border: 1px solid;
   padding: 0px 80px 0px 80px;
   background: #ddd;
}

.tabs input[type=radio]:checked ~ .tabs label {
   background: #fff;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

The problem here is the style of label does not change when radio button is chosen. Can anyone help me to explain it, thanks

btw: I run code using IE 8. Does it support checked properties

Comment: For IE8 you need `input[type=radio][checked]`

Answer (score 3):

Check following is the solution. Replace `~` with `+`.

```css
.tabs label {
   margin-left: -1px;
   border: 1px solid;
   padding: 0px 80px 0px 80px;
   background: #ddd;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
   background: #fff;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
   <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
       <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1"/>
   <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label> 
</div>
```

Comment: one more question what difference between + and ~

Comment: @TranDuyLinh `+` is for the next sibling where `~` is general sibling selector. refer http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/adjacent-sibling-selector-css-selector/ and http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/general-sibling-selector-css-selector/

Comment: @TranDuyLinh IE8 has partial support for pseudo classes.  I think you have to try [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `tilde (~)` sign and replace with `+` and the `.tabs`

```
.tabs input[type=radio]:checked + label {
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also make a jQuery approach:

```
$('.tabs input[type="radio"]').click(function() {

   if($('#tab-1').is(':checked')) { 
       $('#tab-1').addClass("someClass")
   }

});
```

Comment: I only want to use css and html